# Intercept PageUp / PageDown keydown events in Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, dom-events

I have some input elements that the users are request special behavior on <kbd>pageup</kbd> / <kbd>pagedown</kbd> keys to modify value in input element. What the users do not want is to have the scrolling region they are editing in also do a page up/down scroll.  I have it working correctly in Firefox and IE8.

However, in Chrome, I cannot find a way to prevent the browser itself from using these keyboard events to scroll the region.  Before anyone suggests it, calling `e.stopPropagation()` or `e.immediateStopPropagation()` does not solve the problem in Chrome.  It works fine in Firefox and IE8.

Also, the page up/down behavior is to only modified for these special input fields.  For all others, page up/down is to work normally.

You can see a working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/photo_tom/CN4UZ/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used `e.preventDefault()`. Works in Chrome 16.

http://jsfiddle.net/CN4UZ/5/

Answer (score 0):

Works fine in Chrome for me.

```
Google Chrome   17.0.963.12 (Official Build 114667) dev-m
OS  Windows
WebKit  535.11 (@102901)
JavaScript  V8 3.7.12.6
Flash   11,1,102,55
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.12 Safari/535.11
Command Line    "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --no-startup-window --flag-switches-begin --enable-print-preview --flag-switches-end
Executable Path C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Profile Path    C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```

---

If you do not have my build:

Try using `return false`: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/CN4UZ/4/

Comment: most people won't be on a dev build.